# Feasible to find genetic variations of two samples using RNAseq data?

Tags: rna-seq, snp, variant-calling, variation

I have bulk RNAseq data from two strains of mice from Jackson Lab: C57BL/6 and B6.SJL.

The former expresses a `Ptprc-b` allele and the latter expresses a `Ptprc-a` allele.

They are supposedly isogenic at all other loci. But to the best of my knowledge, there is no empirical evidence of this.

My question is, how would I go about finding all the **homozygous** *single nucleotide* **variations** **(if there are any)** in the coding sequences of the two strains from my RNAseq data.

I should mention that the RNAseq data are paired-end illumina reads ~150bp long.

Comment: Maybe try MMseq or MMseqs2?